# how to clone a list object

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloning

Hi i am trying to clone a object which has a member list object

```
 public class GrossTemplatesInfo
{
    public List<GrossTemplates> grossTemplates { get; set; }
    public object Clone()
    {
        GrossTemplatesInfo other = (GrossTemplatesInfo)this.MemberwiseClone();
        other.grossTemplates = new List<GrossTemplates>(grossTemplates);
        return other;
    }
}
public class GrossTemplates : ICloneable
{
    public string tempID { get; set; }
    public string PreferenceName { get; set; }
    public string PreferenceValue { get; set; }
    public bool isDefault { get; set; } 
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}
```

and my method is something like this

```
public static GrossTemplatesInfo LoadInitialdata(string caseType)
    {
        GrossTemplatesInfo a = new GrossTemplatesInfo();
       GrossTemplatesInfo b = a.Clone() as GrossTemplatesInfo; 
    }
```

I have done this and i am not getting the values in cloned object 'b' that are in original object 'a'. any help? i am kinda new to this cloning mechanism.

Comment: i need to clone GrossTemplatesInfo object in above code , how can i acheive it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep cloning objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: updated my code , do i need to do member wise clone in class GrossTemplatesInfo too?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing context what do you need

Comment: I need to clone the GrossTemplatesInfo object

Comment: what is going wrong in the above code? the cloned object 'b' is not showing the values that are in a.

Comment: @Sheiky you are creating a list with original values in it. You need to copy the inner content too: `other.grossTemplates = new List<GrossTemplates>(grossTemplates.Select(i => (GrossTemplates)i.Clone());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to clone your container class, so you need to implement ICloneable on it too (GrossTemplatesInfo).

Dealing with the GrossTemplates class, three possibilities:

1, Do it manually:

```
public object Clone()
{
    return new GrossTemplates()
    {
        tempId = this.tempId,
        PreferenceName = this.PreferenceName,
        PreferenceValue = this.PreferenceValue,
        IsDefault = this.IsDefault
    };
}
```

2, Use a generic helper as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) (cf @Uriil comment)

3, Rethink the whole context (or explain it to us) and [do not copy instances](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm)

If applicable, 3 is the way to go.